# Permanently disabling Driver Signing Check

Tags: windows-7, drivers

I require to use some unsigned drivers on a Windows 7 x64 system.

I Googled around and found a post which says to use `bcdedit` and switch test mode on and then  to disable integrity check. But it did not work :(

So now, to use those drivers I need to press <kbd>F8</kbd> each time I boot and then Select "Disable Driver Signing Enforcement".

So, is there any way to stop the check?

Comment: Use solution 2: http://www.techspot.com/community/topics/how-to-install-use-unsigned-drivers-in-windows-vista-7-x64.127187/ set the new entry as the default seleciton.

Answer (score 3):

Best way would be to sign the driver itself, plenty ways to do it if you google it -

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/9b6eee60-855d-47cc-9927-acae3fb6f971/permanently-disable-driver-signature-enforcement-on-win-7-x64.